# Find total energy and momentum of an moving electron in a rest frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, momentum, electrons

I have an electron moving with speed $u'$ in a frame $S'$ moving with speed $v'$ relative to a rest frame $S$.

How do I find the total energy and momentum of the electron in the rest frame $S$?

I thought the equations were:

$E_{total} = \gamma \times mc^2$
$p = \gamma \times mv$

But, that doesn't look right... Could someone point out to me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply calculate the velocity of the electron in frame S. You can either sit down and work it out using the Lorentz transforms, or just use the [relativistic velocity addition formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula).

Answer (score 1):

Your equations are correct you just have to be careful about their meaning.

In an inertial frame $S$, the energy and momentum of a particle of mass $m$ are given by
$$E_S = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}},\quad \text{and} \quad \vec{p}_S=\frac{m \vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
where $v$ is the speed of the particle *relative to $S$*.

If you can work out the velocity of the particle relative to $S$, your formulae will give you the correct answer. However, you have only been given $v^\prime$, the velocity with respect to $S^\prime$. You can compute $v$ using the velocity addition formula.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity-addition formulae should indeed give the correct answer.  Here's what happens if you work it out using vector Lorentz transformations.

We know that the four-velocity of the electron is $S'$ frame is $\tilde u = W(ce_t' + ue_x')$, where $W=(1-[u/c]^2)^{-1/2}$.  Some notes on notation: $\tilde u$ denotes the four-vector while $u$ is just the three-velocity.  I'm calling this Lorentz factor $W$ to avoid confusion with the Lorentz factor of the boost (which will just be $\gamma$).  So once again, $u$ goes with $W$ the way $v$ goes with $\gamma$.

Now then, the boost between the $S,S'$ frames tells us that $e_t' = \gamma( e_t + v e_x/c)$ and $e_x' = \gamma(e_x + v e_t/c)$.  We can be very mechanical here and just plug these expressions back into our original four-velocity.  The result is

$$\tilde u = W(c[\gamma(e_t + ve_x/c)] + u[\gamma(e_x + ve_t/c)])=W\gamma([c+uv/c]e_t+\gamma[u+v]e_x)$$

Take $\tilde p = m_e \tilde u$, and you're done.  The components fall out as

$$E/c = m_e W\gamma(c + uv/c), \quad p = m_e W\gamma(u + v)$$

In the limiting case that the boost velocity $v=0$, then $\gamma=1$ and we get $E/c=m_e W c \implies E = m_e W c^2$, which checks, and $p = m_e W u$, which also checks.  Similarly, if $u=0$, then $W=1$, the correct limits hold, too.  It's always a good idea to check limits; doing so helped me find a mistake in this calculation which I've since corrected!

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Taking all motion to be along the x/x' axis, the [energy-momentum 4-vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) (we'll only use 2 components since this is a 1 dimension problem spatially) in the primed frame is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
E'/c\\
p_x'\\
\end{array}
\right) = m \ \gamma\left(u'\right)  \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c\\
u'\\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
where $\gamma\left(u\right) = 1/\sqrt{1-\left(u/c\right)^2}$. Now just [Lorentz transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Boost_in_the_x-direction) to get the energy-momentum 4-vector in the unprimed frame:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
E/c\\
p_x\\
\end{array}
\right) &=& \gamma\left(v'\right) \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & v'/c  \\
  v'/c & 1 
 \end{pmatrix} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
E'/c\\
p_x'\\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 &=& m \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & v'/c  \\
  v'/c & 1 
 \end{pmatrix} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c\\
u'\\
\end{array}
\right) \\
&=& m \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right)  \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c + u' v' / c\\
v' + u' \\
\end{array}
\right). \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So,
$$
E = m c^2 \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \left(1 + u' v' / c^2\right)
$$
and
$$
p_x = m \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \left(v' + u'\right).
$$
**Method 2**

Using the [relativistic velocity addition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_theory_of_relativity), the velocity in the unprimed frame is
$$
u = \frac{u' + v'}{1 + u' v' / c^2}.
$$
Noting that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma\left(u\right) &=&  \left[1-\frac{1}{c^2}\left(\frac{u' + v'}{1 + u' v' / c^2}\right)^2\right]^{-1/2}  \\
&=&  \frac{1+u' v' / c^2}{\sqrt{1 + \left(u' v' / c^2\right)^2 - \left(u'/c\right)^2 - \left(v'/c\right)^2}} \\
&=& \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \left(1 + u' v' / c^2\right),
\end{eqnarray}
$$
the energy in the unprimed frame is
$$
E = \gamma\left(u\right) m c^2 = m c^2 \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \left(1 + u' v' / c^2\right),
$$
and the momentum in the unprimed frame is
$$
p_x = \gamma\left(u\right) m u = m \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \left(1 + u' v' / c^2\right) \left(\frac{u' + v'}{1 + u' v' / c^2}\right) = m \ \gamma\left(v'\right)\gamma\left(u'\right) \left(v' + u'\right),
$$
which are in agreement with Method 1.